# SQL result shows: Invalid column name error

Tags: sql, jpa

Here is my code in JPA, and I got an error shows "Invalid column name"

```
@Query(value = "SELECT fs.NAME, MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) " +
"FROM TABLE.SEARCH fs " +
"WHERE fs.NAME LIKE %:name%" +
"GROUP BY fs.NAME " +
"ORDER BY MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) DESC, fs.NAME", nativeQuery = true)
List<SearchFile> findAllByNameLikeOrderByUpdatedAtDesc(@Param("name") String name);
```

[image]
I have data: `test test1 test1 test2 test2 new new1`, and I want to retrieve data like `test test1 test2` .

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace with the full error mesage?

Comment: Likely you have to assign an alias to `MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT)` , based on your error

Comment: Hi, I had post the error message image.

Comment: there is no where in the stacktrace. could you remove the % from the query and add them to the name variable before passing it by parameter to the method query invocation?